# Checking order of magnitude of functions

Tags: function, big-o, magnitude

I am going through self study of theory of automate. I need some help in solving out the following problem:

If `f(n) = O(n2)` and `g(n) = O(n3)` then how can I prove
whether `g(n)/f(n) = O(n)` holds?

Comment: You should add some calculations or thought you have done before you got stuck and ask how to come over the exact problem. Otherwise you most likely are going to get down voted. You should also read ["the tour"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), "[how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and [more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: To try to prove it, try applying the definition of big-O notation. To try to disprove it, try looking for counterexamples. Make sure to keep in mind the difference between big-O and big-theta.